# Searching for substring in the main string through VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code below with the help of which I am trying to achieve pattern matching.

The snapshot shown below is the data from Sheet2.I have **ShortDescription** which is the main string and the corresponding number in **Inc No**

[image]

Another snapshot is from Sheet3. I have **Keyword** which is the substring that I want to find in the **ShortDescription** from Sheet2 and **Output** is the desired output which is the all the corresponding **Inc No** against values found in the main string.

[image]

So far, I have written the below code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim str2, Cell, intVal As Variant
str2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A2").Value
For Each Cell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A4")
    intVal = Cell.Value
    If intVal Like "*" & str2 & "*" Then
        MsgBox "Got it"
    End If
    Next Cell   
End Sub
```

So for example, Tushar is 2 times in main string. MsgBox is coming 2 times. This is just there to check that my code is working so far. I dont know how to proceed.

Comment: Instead of a message box, add the number to a string variable and concatenate as you go.

Comment: I did not get you @SJR . I have to add which number to which string?

Comment: Build a string based on the cell to the right of those which satisfy your condition. If it doesn't make any sense I'll post an answer.

Comment: I know you are making sense but I am not able to write the code.I have to submit the report by evening and dont know what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me. Assign it to your button. However, it might be better to turn it into a custom function and then you can apply to multiple cells.

```
Sub x()

Dim str2 As Variant, Cell As Range, s As String

With ThisWorkbook
    str2 = .Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A2").Value
    For Each Cell In .Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A4")
        If Cell.Value Like "*" & str2 & "*" Then
            s = s & vbLf & Cell.Offset(, 1).Value   'add col B number and line feed to the string
        End If
    Next Cell
    .Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B2").Value = Mid(s, 2) 'return final string missing initial line feed
End With

End Sub
```